# sql: i need help in figuring out a query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have three 3 tables (classes, module , module_classes) suppose for simplicity they are as follow:
class table:

```
+-----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id  |  name   |  level   |  deleted  |create_time|
+-----|---------+----------|-----------+-----------+
|1    | C1      |4         | 1         |some date  |
|2    | C2      |2         | 0         |some date  |
|3    | C1      |1         | 0         |some date  | 
+-----+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

module table:

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| id  |  name   |  deleted |
+-----|---------+----------|
|1    | M1      |0         |
|2    | M2      |0         | 
|3    | M1      |0         |  
+-----+---------+----------+
```

module_class table:

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| id  | classId | moduleId |
+-----|---------+----------|
|1    | 1       |1         |
|2    | 2       |2         |
|3    | 1       |3         | 
+-----+---------+----------+
```

the level increase by one every semester, after 4 semester the class will be set to be delete and new class with same name but with level 1 will be inserted, the module will stay the same, the class id in module_class must be update from the deleted one to the inserted class,so it must become like this :

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| id  | classId | moduleId |
+-----|---------+----------|
|1    | 3       |1         |
|2    | 2       |2         |
|3    | 3       |3         | 
+-----+---------+----------+
```

i could not figure how to make it possible, any suggestion about how could  that be done? thanks in advance

Comment: CAN YOU EXPLAIN WHATS NOT POSSIABLE ? is it adding the 3rd entry in last table or something else

Comment: you can do it using triggers set on update trigger for 1st table and for each update record check level value if it 4 then set deleted flag and insert one record to same table with new class details and another record to module_class table

Comment: then once you update level on 1st  table it will automatically update the rest

Comment: if you want that trigger format just comment i can provide it

Comment: i have no idea about triggers it would be awesome if you provide me some info about that or maybe some resource about triggers

Comment: ill provide you the required trigger

Comment: thanks a lot much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this trigger

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS TRIGGER_class_UPDATE;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_class_UPDATE BEFORE UPDATE ON class FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
   SET @moduleId= (SELECT moduleId FROM module_class WHERE class_id=old.id);
   IF NEW.level=4 THEN 
      SET NEW.deleted=1;
      INSERT INTO class(name,level,deleted,create_time) values (old.name,1,0,now());
        set @newclassid=(SELECT ID FROM class WHERE name=old.anem and deleted=0 and level=old.level);
       INSERT INTO module_class(classId,moduleId) values (@newclassid,@moduleId);
   ELSE
      SET NEW.deleted=0;
   END IF;
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html

Comment: NEW value means latest values which is going to update and old value means already available value in that record

Comment: trigger looks awesome,but i think you got me wrong, i want to only update the module_class table and set the old calssId in module_calss equal to new classId inserted in classes table,

Comment: you did in this trigger what other query do,but not exactly the same if i have to edit it to make it clear about what i did and what should i do from the beginning, should i?